# Passing dom nodes into a Knockout component (when using RequireJS)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to translate this [example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-markup-into-components) to AMD with the requireJS.

As an example I choose the "base-window" widget:

```
<base-window params="title: 'Window title'">
    <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
    <p>This is a body of the window</p>
</base-window>
```

See [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6hQcCAGGxMnaYaeei7En?p=preview).

The body of the window is not shown however. Browser says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return {nodes:$componentTemplateNodes} }"
Message: $componentTemplateNodes is not defined
```

Could anyone say what's wrong?

Comment: Typo in `base-window.js`. Hilighted by plunker.o

Comment: Thank you. Fixed. Does not solve the problem.

Comment: Your plunker contains *a lot* of code to go through, but the question contains a bit too little. Please make sure the question can stand on its own, and include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context variable `$componentTemplateNodes` is available only starting with KO version 3.3

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hFV8G7OERyZ7z8uP5tmD?p=preview)